# Strange Operating with String.split differently with user input

Tags: java, string, input, split

I can not get my head around this.

```
System.err.println(convertPdfToText(save).split("3\\.8").length);
```

as expected prints out a result of 3.

In fact, I want a user to be able to obtain the same. Therefore, when I run this code:

```
System.err.println(convertPdfToText(save).split(seperator).length);
```

When the user has entered "3\\.8" in a JInputField, I get the length of the array being returned as 1.

What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"\\"` in a Java program represents a string containing one `\`. In your case, the user would have to enter `3\.8` to get the string represented by the Java code `"3\\.8"`.

That is, you seem to be confused by the difference between Java's syntax for string literals (which treats `\` and `"` specially) and strings entered from external sources (where every character stands for itself).

Comment: surely it would be four slashes, not one?

Comment: So in my example, the \\ stands as a single slash ? And how would one go about changing the user input as 3.8 to to the required input?

Comment: You'd have to walk through the string and insert a backslash before every `.`, I guess.